# The hub sends larger chunks than it receives them

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have the Hub which takes the file, saves into the private static property and later sends it file back to the caller user.

```
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {

        private static string _file;

        public async Task SendAudio(IAsyncEnumerable<string> stream)
        {
            var enumerator = stream.GetAsyncEnumerator();
            await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
            _file = enumerator.Current;
        }
        
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReceiveFile([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            yield return _file;
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs when I'm looking in the websocket panel.

[image]

- The first red frame (send file) shows length is 57122 bytes.
- The second red frame (receive file) shows length is 146515 bytes.

Why is the difference so great?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to send binary data. Json doesn't support binary data, instead you're supposed to base64 encode your data before giving it to Json, and on the server side you would either base64 decode it, or store it as a base64 blob. The reason you're seeing a difference here is that your client side is taking the bytes you gave it and just directly using them as their UTF8 value. However on the server side when it sends the same data back it will see that some of the UTF8 data isn't safe and will do some extra encoding to make sure it is safe, hence the different size.

If you want to avoid having to base64 encode your blobs, you can give the Message Pack protocol a try which supports byte[] directly. https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/messagepackhubprotocol?view=aspnetcore-3.1